# Using ACF on taxonomy and keeps on getting image src undefined

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy, advanced-custom-fields

I got this Wordpress site with a slideshow where I get the images from advanced custom fields repeater, but the source keeps on getting undefined. It's a taxonomy page and I use this following code:

```
<section class="slider">
    <?php

    $queried_object = get_queried_object();
    $taxonomy = $queried_object->taxonomy;
    $term_id = $queried_object->term_id;

    $slider_images = array();

    while (has_sub_field('slider_bilder')):
        $image_src = the_sub_field('slider_bild', $taxonomy . '_' . $term_id);
        $slider_images [] = $image_src;


    endwhile;
    // As slider images starts with the last image so we will reverse the images in the array so ordering the images in the admin section could be easier
    $rv_slider_images = array_reverse($slider_images);
    foreach ($rv_slider_images as $slider_image) {
        ?>
        <img src='<?php echo $slider_image; ?>' alt='' />
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</section>
```

The result I get is this:

```
<img src="undefined" alt="" style="opacity: 0.775823;">
```

I really can't get this one right.

My `$taxonomy` and `$term_id` generates the correct values and the code for the slideshow works fine on the other pages so for some reason I can't get the values from the ACF. Why and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

look documentation for acf repeater [here](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/repeater/) and try replace `the_sub_field('slider_bild', $taxonomy . '_' . $term_id);` to this `get_sub_field('slider_bild', $taxonomy . '_' . $term_id);`

Comment: Still getting the src as defined

Comment: try use `var_dump($image_src)` and `var_dump($slider_images)` and show what u get

Comment: If I try to do a `var_dump`  in the `while loop` nothing happens, so I guess that it fails already with `has_sub_field('slider_bilder')`. If i declare `$image_src` before the loop it returns `bool(false)`

Comment: try use `while (has_field('slider_bilder')):` I think problem with get repeat field

Comment: u can use `has_sub_field` only with this structure:
`<?php if(get_field('repeater_field_name')): ?>

 <ul>

 <?php while(has_sub_field('repeater_field_name')): ?>

  <li>sub_field_1 = <?php the_sub_field('sub_field_1'); ?>, sub_field_2 = <?php the_sub_field('sub_field_2'); ?>, etc</li>

 <?php endwhile; ?>

 </ul>

<?php endif; ?>`

Comment: But my code above works fine on the other pages, so I don't think its a problem with that part, but that I can't get the value from `slider_bilder`. `has_field` doesn't even exists but I tried `have_rows` but that didn't work either.

Comment: maybe try use this: 
`while (has_sub_field('slider_bilder'), $taxonomy . '_' . $term_id):`

Comment: You're welcome. Can u marker this question like resolved?